# How to auto run Web Application by Net Beans

Tags: jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I'm using glassfish server and I'm using this to start the glasshfish without opening the netbeans IDE 7.0

C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\bin>domain1Service.
exe Start

but when I go to the browser and manually input the URL it's 404
The requested resource () is not available.

Why is that? how can I make my web app run? please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server software is what fetches the webpage and display in the browser, if your server software is not started, it cannot fetch the webpage in your system,you could make the server software start even in the system startup by writing a `batch file (.bat)` and put it in the startup folder of your `C:\Windows`
or making the server software as a service

http://tim-sparg.blogspot.in/2010/08/installing-glassfish-as-windows-service.html

http://www.coderanch.com/t/512064/java/start-Galssfish-Computer-start

Comment: well, the glassfish is starting but I cant fetch my website made out of netbeans? why is that?

Comment: @SigfredChamo its because your jsp code has to be debugged first

Comment: @SigfredChamo its because your jsp code has to be debugged first, after execution of the jsp code only the server software fetches the page,

Comment: so u mean, there is no way to start my web app without opening the net beans? cause i also tried the tomcat and it's the same...

Comment: No you can do it, glassfish server is dedicated to netbeans , install apache and copy your project to the 'webapps' folder of it ,start apache and you can access your site

Comment: it's not working... I manually started the tomcat and put my project inside the 'webapps' and visited the localhost:8080/MyProject and tried localhost:8080/webapps/MyProject...

Comment: oh I forgot i changed the port 8081... now it's working fine...hahaha thankz man... i really appreciate your help.

Comment: how and where? sorry just new

Comment: Sarath, it's not working... I need to build it in netbeans b4 it can be able to run... How can I build my project without using NETBEANS